# Identify IC manufacturer by logo

Tags: integrated-circuit, bluetooth

What is name of the IC manufacturer with this logo?

[image]

Probably it is Chinese manufacturer. I wasn't able to find it [here](https://www.elnec.com/en/support/ic-logos/) or [here](https://how-to.fandom.com/wiki/How_to_identify_integrated_circuit_(chip)_manufacturers_by_their_logos/all_logos).

I need to find specification or datasheet of its audio bluetooth reciever circuits 1748NRZ-11F and 17280-11C.

These chips are used in bluetooth car media players like [this one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32920114102.html).

Comment: Googling 1914SRZ is returning a bunch of seemingly relevant results. Not the IC manufacturer though.

Comment: I know, almost each link is going to aliexpress store. But i can't  find any datasheet.

Answer (score 5):

Manufacturer company name is Appotech